# iOS how to add a view to screen center and stick it to screen center on a UITableViewController?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm working on a `UITableViewController`. I have to display a `view` with some info, that view will be added to the `TableViewController` programatically. This is my code of adding it:

```
MyNotificationView *notificationView = // some initializations;
[self.view addSubview:notificationView]; // self is the UITableViewController
notificationView.center = self.view.center;
```

However on `UITableViewController`, this code actually sets the center of my `notificationView` to the center of the scrollable area of the `TableViewController`, and my `notificationView` scrolls as the `TableView` scrolls. 
What I want is to add my `notificationView` to the screen center and stick it there, so how can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a UIViewController with an UITableView inside and the notificationView you want to keep in center, just add it to view `[self.view addSubview:notificationView];`

Comment: Actually, I have some static cells so I have to use `UITableViewController`. Although I can embed a `UITableViewController` in a normal `UIViewController`, but that is a little too much work. Is there an easy workaround for my situation?

Comment: if you're using storyboard you can do static cells in TableView too

Comment: Can I? I got the "Static table views are only valid when embedded in UITableViewController instances" error. Looks like I have to go with  the embedding a `UITableViewController` in a `UIViewController` way, after I have done that, I found it is actually not so much work as I thought ^_^